# Evaluate $\oint \limits_C \frac{z^2+1}{(2z-i)^2}dz$ using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Let $C:|z|=1$ be a circle with positive orientation. Use residue to evaluate $$\oint \limits_C \frac{z^2+1}{(2z-i)^2}dz$$

Our integrand (let's call it $f$) has one singular point (pole) of order two, $z=\frac{1}{2}i$ in $C$.

Now, we can find \begin{align}\text{Res}\bigg[~f,\frac{1}{2}i\bigg] &= \lim_{z \to \frac{1}{2}i} \bigg( \frac{(z-\frac{1}{2}i)(z^2 +i)}{(2z -i)^2}\bigg) \\ \end{align}

I need help evaluating this limit in order to determine $$\oint \limits_C \frac{z^2+1}{(2z-i)^2}dz = 2\pi i\text{Res}\bigg[~f,\frac{1}{2}i\bigg] $$

Or should I rather use another method of finding the Residue?

Comment: the formula for the residue is not correct, because we have to deal with a second order pole here

Comment: This method works only for simple pole. You'll surely find the right formula in the wikipedia Residue article. Note: the integral can also be computed using only Cauchy's integral formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the incorrect expression for the residue.  For a double pole,

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=i/2} \frac{z^2+1}{(z-i/2)^2} = \lim_{z \to i/2} \frac{d}{dz}\left [ \left (z-\frac{i}{2} \right )^2\frac{z^2+1 }{(z-i/2)^2} \right ]$$

Comment: @Surb: That's assuming one knows to take the factor of $2$ out of the original expression.  I just wrote the residue for a double pole.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $f$ is holomorphic in the domain $\text{Int}(C)$, Cauchy says $$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\mathrm d z.$$

Comment: Thank you! :). I know the Generalised Cauchy Integral Formula, but the question explicitly states that we must use the residue theorem (I'm preparing for an exam and this was one of the questions in a past paper). So I don't think I'm allowed to use this to answer the question :(

Comment: They are both equivalent. And the consequence is that $Res(f,\frac{1}{2}i)=\frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$.

Comment: That's great then! :D. So I can let $f(z) = z^2 +1$, then say $$\text{Res}\bigg[f, \frac{i}{2}\bigg] = \frac{2z}{1!} \bigg|_{z=\frac{i}{2}}$$ and then have $$\oint \limits_{C} \frac{z^2 +1}{(2z -i)^2}dz = 2\pi i ~\text{Res}\bigg[f, \frac{i}{2}\bigg]$$

Comment: Yes it's the idea but $f(z)=\frac{z^2+1}{4}$ and not $z^2+1$. @user229672